# Не могу создать конструктор ButtonListener

Tags: java

Прохожу видеокурс от Тимура Батыршинова и вот наткнулся на такую проблему:

```
public class BtnNewY implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel jPanel;

    public ButtonListener (JPanel jPanel){
        this.jPanel = jPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

Не могу создать конструктор ButtonListener в intellij idea, ругается.

Что посоветуете делать?

Comment: Оформите картинки в виде текста, пожалуйста. Тут нет необходимости в картинках.

Comment: Как отредактировать пост?

Comment: Пройдите по этой ссылке, чтобы отредактировать вопрос: [Правка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/462699/edit)

Comment: Вы радикально изменили вопрос. Что за звёздочки у метода `ButtonListener`?

Comment: Я выделил ButtonListener и кликнул на B (Bold)... Хотел выделить именно название...

Comment: Где сам класс `ButtonListener` для которого вы пытаетесь написать конструктор? И где вы создаёте объект этого класса?

Comment: Я не знаю где этот класс, он, насколько я понял из видео, он должен быть стандартным в java... Из видео можно увидеть, как Eclipse сам подсказывает вставить этот конструктор. Я вот и подумал, может что то симпортировать надо, класс какой-нибудь? В этом видео показывается как создать ActionListener для кнопки из внешнего (не внутреннего класса).

Comment: Что вы называете конструктором?

Comment: LEQADA, большое спасибо за наводящие вопросы!!! :) В видео класс в котором создавался конструктор так и назывался... Сорри!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конструктор должен иметь имя равное имени класса. Если класс имеет имя `BtnNewY` то и конструктор должен быть таким:

```
public BtnNewY (JPanel jPanel){
    this.jPanel = jPanel;
}
```

Comment: Вы, наверное, хотели сказать "название", а не "тип".

Comment: LEQADA, именно!!! :)
ЮрийСПб, спасибо!

Comment: Ну, пожалуй, да. Сложно мне понять как это правильно назвать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, просто "тип" чаще используют, когда говорят о типах данных: char, int, float и т.д.

Comment: @Seomat, если ответ решил проблему, то его надо бы отметить верным, нажав галочку слева от тела ответа.

Comment: Кликнул на стрелочку, а он ругнулся на то что у меня с репутацией что то не так... у меня 9 а надо 15 кажется...

Comment: @Seomat, это вам система не даёт проголосовать "за" ответ. А принять ответ можно с любой репутацией. Для этого есть кнопка "галочка" снизу от стрелок "за" и "против" ответа.

Comment: Спасибо! А я и не знал что такое есть... Круто!

Comment: @Seomat, добро пожаловать на ru-SO) Теперь, кстати, вам репутации должно хватать и на голосование за хорошие вопросы/ответы)

Comment: Уже проголосовал! :)